# @ManagedBean not getting invoked on page load

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am kinda new to Java and JSF but here goes:

In eclipse, a new JSF project:

I have configured hibernate/jpa etc. Eclipse can communicate with Postgres Database and create tables from entities.

I have declared a Entity called BlogPost, and a BlogPostController (managed logic for the BlogPost entity).

The index.xhtml file extends a template called base.xhtml which defines several regions.
I am trying to reference a managed bean method from within index.xhtml using ui:repeat and h:dataTable but **nothing** appears even though there's an entry in the database for blogposts.

I am also not getting **any** errors in the logs.
Someone please help, i'll be glad to provide more information should something be missing.

```
package org.nps2.blog.beans;

import java.util.List;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.nps2.blog.controllers.BlogPostController;
import org.nps2.blog.models.*;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ManagedBean
public class Homepage {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private List<BlogPost> blogposts;
private List<User> users;

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Homepage.class.getName());

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Inject
private BlogPostController c;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    log.info("HELLO THERE");
    return (users);
}

public List<BlogPost> getBlogposts() {
    log.info("HELLO THERE");
    return (c.getAll());
}

public void setBlogposts(List<BlogPost> blogposts) {
    this.blogposts = blogposts;
}
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{homepage.blogpost}" var="c"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Customer ID!
            </f:facet>
                #{c.id}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Name
            </f:facet>
                #{c.first_name}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Last name
            </f:facet>
                #{c.last_name}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Username
            </f:facet>
                #{c.username}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Blog</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Added the code, hope it's readable.

Comment: I know very little about EJB and CDI, but shouldn't the class BlogPostController be annotated with something?

Comment: The BlogPostController is a bog standard POJO for convenience only. It has nothing to do with jboss/jsf/etc.

Comment: But doesn't it need to be, in order to work the injection of the EntityManager and the other bean?

Comment: I haven't worked with newer (besides SEAM 2.x) versions of injection, but maybe giving a specific name to the `Homepage` class would do the trick?  Ala, `@ManagedBean(name="homepage")` - [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/) uses that named component syntax.  Also, maybe it is a case-sensitivity issue with any auto-naming that's supported by `@ManagedBean`?  In which case you might try `#{Homepage.blogpost}`.  Although [these docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) seem to contradict that idea...

Comment: Finally worked this out after 2 days.
The Problem is that when i typed in ManagedBean eclipse auto-imported ManagedBean from the wrong place (import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;).

Just spotted this and changed it to the proper (import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked this out when i spotted that Eclipse imported the wrong ManagedBean declaration.

Eclipse automatically imported: javax.annotation.ManagedBean
I changed it to: javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean

That way everything worked, and my bean method got invoked.